# Swiss Embassy Visa Refusal

Tags: visas, visa-refusals

I got research paper accepted in international conference to be held at Zurich, Switzerland. I got my visa rejected with following reason: Justification for the purpose and conditions of the intended stay was not provided.
As i found that i did not mention the reason to stay for more three days after the conference. Basically my purpose was site seeing. As a justification of purpose, i already attached the invitation and acceptance letter from the conference committee.
Should i need to apply for visa again with justification of purpose and stay. If yes, then should i need to mention in the cover letter about the refusal. Please suggest.

Comment: Your university or company (presuming you're being sponsored by an employer to attend the conference) may have someone who can assist you with this.